# How to debug dynamic JavaScript functions in FireBug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have some JavaScript functions like this:

```
function onSelectRow_${itemid}(){
   something;
}
```

This it is appearing like this in Firebug script tab:

```
function onSelectRow_87878(){
     something;
}
```

I put multiple break points (it has more than 20 lines, I put one in for example) in Firebug -> Script tab.

But the problem is, Firebug is not able to do debug these methods, ie. it is not stopping execution it executing as usual. I tried multiple times.

This is my actual code and use:

```
function onSelectRow_${escapedId }(rowId){
}
    

<jqgrid:grid onSelectRow="onSelectDeviceRow_${escapedId }"
```

What can I try to resolve it?

Comment: How are you generating these functions? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

```
function onSelectRow_87878()
{
     debugger; //add here
     something;
}
```

When you open Firebug, enable Script,and it will automatically go to the debugger point

**[debugging in firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)**

Comment: This is going to be my best friend forever(Y)